# error 91 en excel

Tags: excel

me encuentro ejecutando macros desde python, pero tengo una en particular que me ha dado trabjo, el cual me lanza error 91, en un momento me fije que al no encontrar "#N/D" me lanza este error por ello le coloque un condicional antes de ejecutarlo que valide si esta vacio, sin embargo aun me sigue lanzando este error al ejecutarlo.

Este es mi código:

```
Sub EliminarCancelados()
'
' EliminarCancelados Macro
'
    Sheets("Exportar").Select
    Dim Borrar As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Exportar")
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            If .Cells(i, "K").Text = "#N/D" Then
                If Borrar Is Nothing Then
                    Set Borrar = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set Borrar = Union(Borrar, .Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    
    If Not IsEmpty(Borrar) Then
        Borrar.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
      
    
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

y acá una captura del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me da la sensación de que lo que quieres es borrar todas las filas cuyo resultado sea un error en la columna K. Puedes simplificar tu código enormemente beneficiándote de **SpecialCells**, que te permite seleccionar de golpe varias celdas que cumplan una condición específica (dar error en tu caso):

Si tus errores en la columna K vienen de fórmulas, prueba con:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Exportar").Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
```

Si tus errores son ya valores y ya no son formulas entonces:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Exportar").Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).EntireRow.Delete
```

Fuente:

> [Método Range.SpecialCells
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)